# how to RealmMigration for private RealmList<String> datalist for next version in android

Tags: android, realm

My Model class contains following field

```
 class NewOrder{
    @PrimaryKey
    String id = INSTANCE_ID;
    @SerializedName("order")
    @Expose
    private Boolean order;
    @SerializedName("datalist")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<String> datalist ;
    long fetchTimestamp;
}
```

and i wrote function for migration :

```
private void migrationfunction(RealmSchema schema) {
        if (schema.get("NewOrder") == null) {
            RealmObjectSchema newOrderCardSchema = schema.create("NewOrder");
            newOrderCardSchema.addField("order", Boolean.class);
            newOrderCardSchema.addRealmListField("datalist", String.class);
            newOrderCardSchema.addField("fetchTimestamp", long.class);
            newOrderCardSchema.addField("id", String.class);
            newOrderCardSchema.addPrimaryKey("id");

        }

    }
```

but i am confused about RealmList datalist is it correct which i have written  in migrationfunction  please suggest me its correct or wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its correct. According to [RealmObjectSchema,](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmObjectSchema.html#addRealmListField-java.lang.String-io.realm.RealmObjectSchema-) it will adds a new field that references a RealmList with given primitive values.